# Set default team view filter selection on page load in Twilio flex UI - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, twilio, twilio-flex

In the team view filters of Twilio flex UI, I want to set the filter selection dynamically. I need to pass an array or object on dynamically to set the filters selection and the results need to be displayed accordingly based on the new filter selection. Any idea on how to achieve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
let defaultTwilioAgentList = [
  {
      query: 'data.activity_name == "Available" OR data.activity_name == "Idle"',
      text: "Active Agents"
  },
  {
      query: '',
      text: "All Agents"
  },
];
Flex.AgentsDataTable.defaultProps.filters = departmentList;
```

This works for me at Flex version 1.21.1